# Batch action: Crop a photo to two photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions

I have many photos (all of them are of same dimensions), that need to be adjusted according to following example:

IN image:

[image]

OUT images, cropped:

[image] [image]

I have created following action:

[image]

Basically, I have recorded an action, where I cropped the image to create first one, saved, clicked Back, and then cropped for the second image and saved as well. This solution works for me, however there is one problem. The names of these files are following:

- myFir1.jpg
- myFir11.jpg
- mySec2.jpg
- mySec22.jpg

.. so the names are not as expected (myFir1.jpg, myFir2.jpg, mySec1.jpg, mySec2.jpg). The setting of Batch is following:
[image]

Could somebody advise, if possible, how to create expected filenames? I understand that this is more settings-related than graphic-related, but I think that answering this question would complete these step-by-step instructions for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that you have *one* action that saves the image *two* times.

The automatic numbering will always reflect the number of the image being processed, not the number of times an image have been saved by the action.

So the first image will get number 1, but the second time you save it it will get the same number appended to the filename because it hasn't moved on to the next image yet. It's just a subroutine in the same action.

When the batching grabs the second image, the number will increment to 2 and so on.

**A way to work around this problem would be to simply have two separate actions**. One for the left part which always appends the number 1 to the filename and one for the right part which always appends the number 2 to the filename. No automatic numbering needed. These two actions must then be run in two separate batches.

Comment: Actually, this was an example only. I have to create 8 images, so 8 different actions is not a possibility - I need to find a way how to do that by "one click".

Comment: No offense, but it would be more helpful if you disclosed the full complexity to begin with. It's also worth mentioning how many images you are doing. If it's a task you will do every day, it might be worth using spending time to write a script to do this. That way you will have full control over filenames. But if you only do it once in a while and for hundreds or thousands of images in one go, running 8 batches doesn't sound too cumbersome to me. If you are just dividing the image in 8 equal parts it might be possible using slices.

Comment: Just tested the slicing idea. It's easy to record an action, but of course only if the image is divided in equal parts. And you would have to live with the numbering having two digits instead of one.

Comment: Well, I think I will record one action and prepare some shell script to rename according to my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom11, you're welcome. Sounds like an OK hands-on solution. But if you have scripting abilities, you might not find Photoshop scripting hard. It's just JavaScript, but the api is a bit quirky.